# C# перенос слов в строке с разбивкой на определенную длину

Tags: c#

Есть строка: `Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.`

Нужно разбить ее на три части, но сохранять целые слова и переносить на следующую строку только после окончания слова.
Например, разбиваем на три строки:

```
Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut 
lacinia in, elementum id enim. 
Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.
```

Сейчас использую вот такой простой код, но он режет целые слова:

```
int chunkSize = string.Length / 3;
int stringLength = string.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
{
    if (i + chunkSize > stringLength) chunkSize = stringLength - i;                                    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Substring(i, chunkSize));
}
```

Получается на выходе:

```
Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut l
acinia in, elementum id enim. Nu
lla porttitor accumsan tincidunt
.
```

Подскажите как можно проще это реализовать?

**UPDATE**

**Важно: исходная строка может отличаться от приведенной выше. Может содержать любые символы.**

Нашел простое решение здесь https://stackoverflow.com/a/17571171/2127124

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string[] Wrap(this string text, int max)
    {
        var charCount = 0;
        var lines = text.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        return lines.GroupBy(w => (charCount += (((charCount % max) + w.Length + 1 >= max) 
                        ? max - (charCount % max) : 0) + w.Length + 1) / max)
                    .Select(g => string.Join(" ", g.ToArray()))
                    .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если строка содержит N слов (или N - 1 разделитель `' '`) и ее нужно разбить на К частей, то число возможных разбиений - `(N - K + 2) * (N - K + 1) / 2` при условии `N >= K`. Вам какое разбиение из этих подойдет? Любое? Или нужно самое оптимальное (с длинами кусков наиболее близкими к `str.Length / K`)?

Comment: Желательно оптимальное. Думал насчет того, чтобы разбить исходную строку по пробелам через split, а затем сформировать необходимый набор из полученного списка.

Comment: я бы разбил на слова, далее нашёл кол-во слов в строке и выводил бы всё это

Comment: либо банально идти обычным циклом, смотреть, если подошли к концу но слово не закончилось - идём до конца слова и перенос, ну и потом опять также

Answer (score 4):

Идея - найти индексы символов, по которым нужно разбить в идеале (на равные части). Найти все возможные варианты разбиений строки и выбрать вариант с наименьшей ошибкой. За ошибку я решил принять сумму абсолютных значений отклонений выбранных индексов от идеальных.

```
static int Abs(int x) => x >= 0 ? x : -x;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Входной текст
    var str = "Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.";
    // Количество выходных строк
    var numOfParts = 3;
    // Перечень разделителей
    var delimeters = " ";
    // Индексы, по которым надо разбить в идеале
    var idealParts = Enumerable.Range(1, numOfParts - 1)
                               .Select(x => ((str.Length - numOfParts + 1) * x + numOfParts / 2) / numOfParts)
                               .ToArray();
    // индексы всех имеющихся мест, по которым можно разбить
    var indices = str.Select((c, i) => (c: c, i: i))
                     .Where(t => delimeters.Contains(t.c))
                     .Select(t => t.i)
                     .ToArray();
    // indices.Length ^ numOfParts
    var numOfSp = Enumerable.Range(0, numOfParts - 1)
                            .Aggregate(1, (m, x) => m * indices.Length);
    // Генерируем все возможные комбинации
    var splits = new int[numOfSp][];
    for (int d = 0; d < numOfSp; ++d)
    {
        var z = d;
        splits[d] = new int[numOfParts - 1];
        for (int i = numOfParts - 2; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            splits[d][i] = z % indices.Length;
            z /= indices.Length;
        }
    }
    // Для каждой комбинации подсчитываем ошибку
    var spWithEr = splits.Select(s => (s: s, er: s.Select((x, i) => Abs(indices[x] - idealParts[i])).Sum()))
                         .ToArray();
    // Находим минимальную ошибку
    var minEr = spWithEr.Min(t1 => t1.er);
    // Выбираем комбинацию с наименьшей ошибкой
    var minSp = spWithEr.First(t => t.er == minEr).s;
    // Отбираем индексы
    var sp = new[] { -1 }.Concat(minSp.Select(x => indices[x])
                                      .Concat(new[] { str.Length }))
                         .ToArray();
    // Разбиваем на строки по индексам из sp
    for (int i = 0; i < sp.Length - 1; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(sp[i] + 1, sp[i + 1] - sp[i] - 1));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Вывод:

```
Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut
lacinia in, elementum id enim.
Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.
```

Оверхед ли это - решать вам

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и код! Вы правы, для моей задачи это избыточно.

Answer (score 1):

Разбиваем строку на слова с помощью метода Split и задаем максимальное количество символов в строке. Затем мы строим каждую строку из слов, разделяя их пробелами и проверяя не привысила ли длина текущий строки максимальную.
Код получается довольно компактным, и пусть он скажет за себя)

```
var inputString = @"Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt";
var words = inputString.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
var maxLengthString = 53;
int wordIndex = 0;
var spaceLetter = " ";
var currentLine = new StringBuilder();
while (true)
{                
    if (currentLine.Length + words[wordIndex].Length + 1 > maxLengthString)// Определяем не привысила ли текущая строка максимальную длину
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
        currentLine.Remove(0, currentLine.Length);
    }
    currentLine.Append(words[wordIndex]);
    currentLine.Append(spaceLetter);
    wordIndex++;
    if(wordIndex == words.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(currentLine);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @pwb я думаю, этот метод должен подойти для вашей задачи

Comment: Это хорошо, что вы нашли. Но тем не менее вопрос был задан и ответы прозвучали:)

Comment: Скажите, а что с запятыми и другими символами в Вашем примере? У меня на выходе получается без запятых и некоторых знаков, например режет символ / :(

Comment: Добавил знаки препинания в регулярное выражение var words = new Regex(@"\w(?<!\d)[\w'-,;.?!]*").Matches(inputString);

Comment: А можно еще цифры? Например Сыр мягкий Сербская Брынза 35% 250г Kuč mlekara,Сербия
По хорошему текст должен быть неизменным.

Comment: Зачем регекспы, по пробелу же можно просто сплитить, тогда точно ничего не потеряется

Comment: Да, действительно можно и сплитиить

Comment: Изменил код с использование сплита