# Разбивка строки на подстроки по двум условиям

Tags: c#, алгоритм, инспекция-кода

Есть строка, необходимо разбить её на подстроки по 2 условиям:

- По длине подстроки (она не должна превышать размера `chunk`)
- По вхождению управляющего символа новой строки `\n`

То есть, нужно разбить строку на блоки, но при этом не как попало, а так, чтобы блоки начинались и оканчивались новыми строками, без разрывов.

Написал вот такой алгоритм, но как-то чересчур громоздко получилось. Вожусь уже довольно долго, поэтому вдохновение иссякло и глаз уже замылился. Прошу помочь.

```
var chunk = 10;
var s = "long-long\n string\n with some\n chars";
var messages = new List<string>();
for (var i = chunk;; i += chunk)
{
    if (i >= s.Length)
    {
        messages.Add(s.Substring(i + 1 - chunk));
        break;
    }

    i = s.LastIndexOf('\n', i >= s.Length ? s.Length - 1 : i, 200);
    if (i <= chunk)
    {
        messages.Add(s.Substring(0, i));
        continue;
    }

    var len = messages.Last().Length;
    messages.Add(s.Substring(len, i - len)); 
}
```

Comment: Т.е. на каждом `\n` нужно разбить обязательно + каждый получившийся кусок разбить по длине строки? А разрыв может быть в любом месте или только по пробелу?

Comment: нет, нужно разбить по длине, но так, чтобы разрыв был на ближайшем `\n`

Comment: @Anatol Можете привести конкретные примеры? Например `s = "aaa\nbbb\nccc\nddd\neee\nfff\nggg\n"; chunk = 10` и `s = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\nbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\nccccccccccccccc\n" ; chunk = 10`.

Comment: Если я правильно понял: нужно взять строку, искать ближайший \n к сотому символу, отрезать в месте разрыва и повторять операцию, пока остаток строки  не взлезет целиком в буфер. Так? А что делать если в каком-то очередном чанке нет вообще переводов строки?

Comment: Т.е. разрыв возможен только по `\n`? Но не обязательно на каждом, главное - чтобы куски были не больше `chunk`, так?

Comment: [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707986/218063) код для "оптимальнейшего" разбиения строки на равные части

Comment: @AK хороший вопрос, но такая ситуация исключена в моём случае. Постановку задачи вы интерпретировали верно

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, посмотрю, но выглядит страшновато, честно говоря )

Comment: @Anatol, условие вашей задачи непонятно. У вас задано количество строк на выходе или что? У вас вся строка умещается в 100 символов, нужно ли ее вообще разбивать?

Comment: `Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\n)(?=.)(?!.*\n(?<=\G[\s\S]{0,100}))")`

Comment: @Anatol всё-же не ясно, что делать со строками в которых перевод строки находится в индексе 100++ ?

Comment: изменил входные данные для всех, кому надо буквально

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понял, то можно сперва разбить строку на куски по `\n`, а потом укрупнить их до требуемой длины:

```
var chunk = 10;
var s = "long-long\n string\n XX\nwith some\n chars";

// Разбиваем на куски по разделителю
string[] parts = s.Split('\n');

// Список с готовыми сообщениями, собранными из кусков
var messages = new List<string>();

// Текущее сообщение, которое собираем из кусков
string message = string.Empty;

foreach (string part in parts)
{
    if (message.Length + part.Length + 1 > chunk)
    {
        // Если текущий кусок не помещается в message по ограничению длины
        messages.Add(message);
        message = part + "\n";
    }
    else
        message += part + "\n";
}

// Если в message что-то осталось
messages.Add(message);
```

Если я понял вас неправильно, и вам нужно получить сообщения, **гарантированно** не превышающие ограничение по длине, то можно поступить так:

```
foreach (string part in parts)
{
    string message = part + "\n";
    while (message.Length > chunk)
    {
        messages.Add(message.Substring(0, chunk));
        message = message.Substring(chunk);
    }

    if (message.Length != 0)
        messages.Add(message);
}
```